# Wrapping JavaScript functions that have properties

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to wrap the `request` node module to add a log statement for every request. Normally this is pretty straight forward:

```js
function wrapper(...args) {
  console.log('Hello');
  return request(...args);
};
```

However, the `request` function has properties such as `request.defaults` that I also need. How might one wrap only the function but keep the properties, without changing the `request` API?

Comment: i can see an extra `)`

Comment: "Wrapping" is just jargon, it doesn't actually wrap the function, you still have full access to the object and its methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ideas for wrapping an existing function while keeping the properties of the function being wrapped:

### Copy properties to new function

First, we create a new function that wraps `request`. Then, we use `Object.assign()` to copy properties from `request` to `wrappedRequest`:

```
function wrappedRequest(...args) {
    console.log('called request!');
    return request(...args);
};

Object.assign(wrappedRequest, request); // copy properties from request to wrappedRequest
```

The thing to keep in mind here is that you are only copying the properties **once**. Any properties that are modified or added after this statement will not be added to your new function.

---

### ES2015 Proxy()

This is the preferred way if it's available. It allows you to capture function calls, property getters, and property setters, even if they are set *after* the proxy is created:

```
const handler = {
    apply: function(target, thisArg, argumentList) {
        console.log('called request!');
        return target.apply(thisArg, argumentList);
    },
};

const wrappedRequest = new Proxy(request, handler);
```

The `handler.apply()` intercepts any calls to `wrappedRequest()`. And by default, getting and setting properties on the proxy will mirror getting and setting properties on the target object, which in this case is `request`.

---

### Further Reading

- [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
- [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: The problem with `Proxy` is AFAIK is it can't actually be substituted for the actual object. For example if you proxy an `HTMLCanvasElement` [you can not pass the proxy to functions that expect a canvas](https://jsgist.org/?src=0cc10a63046769ea1b35b2e3e0d57267).

Answer (score 1):

Probably you should return the `request` function itself without executing it -

```
function wrapper() {
   console.log('logs');
   return request;
}


wrapper()('http://sample.com', (err, rsp, body) => {

   //do something
})

wrapper().defaults({});    //calling the default method
```